# OpsWorks: How to set Chef environment?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, environment, aws-opsworks

Using **AWS OpsWorks**, how would you set environment (staging, production, etc.), which will be applied to **`node.chef_environment`** attribute, and then cookbooks will be able to read this attribute? (I guess this can be done using custom JSON, right?)

I came across this [**link**](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2013-08/msg00380.html) but still do not know how to do.

With **Vagrant**, I can set it in Vagrantfile like this:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  ...
  chef.environment = "local"
  ...
end
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I ended up solving the problem by writing `my_environment_cookbook` which only has this code in its default recipe:

```
if node[:chef_environment] != nil
  node.chef_environment = node[:chef_environment]
end
```

And in the custom JSON of the OpsWorks stack, I had something like this:

```
{
  "chef_environment": "staging"
}
```

Then I included `my_environment_cookbook` in the run list, before the cookbook in which I wanted to get `node.chef_environment` attribute.

Comment: See: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1899

Comment: Hi, the problem is I am using OpsWorks, and I do not know how to set environment. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Thought you were using vagrant? Sounds like a different question.

Comment: My bad for the unclear question. I updated it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon Opsworks does not support native Chef environments at this time. You can manually set the node's environment in a recipe:

```
node.chef_environment = "environment_name"
```

Since Opsworks does not persist data between Chef Client runs, you will need to include this recipe each time you run the cookbook.

You can pull the value for `"environment_name"` from whatever data source you would like: hard code, data bag, node attribute, etc.